# Get a particluar edge attribute of a networkX graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to get a particular edge attribute of all the edges in a graph using `networkx.Graph()`.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('A', 'B', relation='family', weight=6)
G.add_edge('B', 'C', relation='friend', weight=13)
```

To get all edges along with attributes

```
G.edges(data=True)
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'B', {'relation': 'family', 'weight': 6}), ('B', 'C', {'relation': 'friend', 'weight': 13})]
```

To get a particular attribute of all edges - it does not work as expected

```
G.edges(data='relation')
```

Actual output:

```
[('A', 'B', {'relation': 'family', 'weight': 6}), ('B', 'C', {'relation': 'friend', 'weight': 13})]
```

Expected output:

```
[('A', 'B', 'family'), ('B', 'C', 'friend')]
```

How to get the given attribute of all edges?

Comment: What version of Python/networkx are you using?  `G.edges(data='relation')` gives me `EdgeDataView([('A', 'B', 'family'), ('B', 'C', 'friend')])`

Comment: This also, worked for me.  Networkx version 2.3

Comment: Thanks, I updated to networkx 2.4 and it worked.